# XCode and gcc errors

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc

So, I feel like my xcode/gcc/however they are supposed to work together has been broken for a while. Trying to download various technologies (most recently redis) has always ended in sadness. When I tried to make the redis I get

```
-bash-3.2$ make
cd src && make all
    LINK redis-server
/bin/sh: gcc-4.6: command not found
make[1]: *** [redis-server] Error 127
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is the kind of error I've been gettng forever. For reference, I'm running Mac 10.7.5, my latest xcode is 4.6 and my latest gcc is 4.2. Any ideas on how I can make this work? I'd rather not upgrade my Mac OS if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know if this is the right way to fix this, but this issue became so problematic for me that I was willing to try anything. I noticed that I definitely had a

```
/usr/bin/gcc
```

file. And I notice that my system couldn't find the `/gcc-4.6`.

So.... I just did one of these numbers

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.6
```

and voila. It works now. Now I can do it all, including essential tasks like compiling any C code. So, hopefully this helps someone out.